# SimpleExoPlayer is deprecated in 2.16. version of ExoPlayer. What to use now?

Tags: android, deprecated, exoplayer

`SimpleExoPlayer` is deprecated in **2.16** version of `ExoPlayer`. What to use now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Github release notes for 2.16.0 version -> https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/RELEASENOTES.md

Deprecate `SimpleExoPlayer`. All functionality has been moved to `ExoPlayer` instead. `ExoPlayer.Builder` can be used instead of `SimpleExoPlayer.Builder`.

Comment: Any thoughts on a warning I am getting that ExoPlayer.Building is also deprecated? I am trying to use the (Context) variant, but when I click to look at the deprecation, it just navigates to the function (Context, Renderers). If that is truly the best way to create exoplayers, it's unclear to me what the default input should be.